# What is the best approach to get data from paging 3 to Nested Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-paging-3

I am implementing an explore screen where I have a parent recycler view that has a title and child recycler view that load movies using paging3 from api and save them to database through Remote Mediator.

Now, My question is what is the best approach to handle loading the data from paging3 to each child recycler view like getting popular movies and top rated ,etc.

[image: Explore Image]

Comment: Based on your response and Inside recyclerview more complex if you're able to interact with api,database and UI you can use...  Title's are static mean you can go with seprate recyclerview.

Comment: The issue is how to load movies data for each category from the api through the parent recycler view. I did it by passing viewmodel to the parent adapter and listening for the data on the parent recyclerview but I think it's a bad approach @GobuCSG

Comment: Share your sample response or make array inside array...

Comment: Don't make complex.. title are fixed mean create nested views.... Recyclerview inside recyclerview more complex... You've to handle properly otherwise lag